# Suggest me where possibly the error can lie in this code,segmentation error, multithreaded network simulator

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, segmentation-fault, cout

I am working on a network simulator which involves generating random connection requests, making connections and releasing them after a specific service time, also generated randomly.
My code is 1000 lines long code. I am using multi-threading and this code is a part of one of two threads. 
I am always getting the same error(segmentation fault) always after the same statement in the code(after the "connection request between _ and _ line:").

error-

```
mokamaConnection request between 10 and 4 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

A very small part of my code which contain the statement after which error is coming. I had added cout statements both above and below the statement after which error is coming.

code-

```
cout<<"mokama"; 
//generate the value of src and dest    
cout<<"Connection request between "<<src<<" and "<<dest<<endl;
//initmat(topocust,0);      //topocust matrix intialised with all zero
cout<<"this printed before matrix.";
```

I know what segmentation error means. But what i am really unable to understand is that how this error can possibly be occur after a cout statement.Is this even possible? I know i should show you the entire code but i can't since it is not feasible. Can anyone without looking at the entire code can suggest me where the problem should lie.. 
Also, since i know the entire code so i can say confidently that problem lie in this thread only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by building your program with debug information (add the `-g` flag), then run your program in a debugger. The debugger will stop when the crash happens, at the location of the crash. You can then examine and walk up the function call stack, walk up to your code (if the crash happens in a system function), and there you can examine values of variables to see if they all look okay. At the very least, edit your question to include the function call stack.

Comment: Since you're not flushing the last `cout`, it's impossible to know whether you've reached it before the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will sound weird but if you are using CodeBlocks IDE, CodeBlocks may sometimes refer to wrong lines of code when segmentation errors appear (don't know why). You may try looking at the code above the indicated line.